# iOS app freezes, but doesn't crash?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

So my app freezes and won't response to touch events. It doesn't crash it just sits there?

If I push the pause button ||, it stops on the following line of code.

```
 NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

If I then push play that app is still frozen and if I push pause again its still point to the above line of code.

Here is the full code where it pauses.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [self entityDescriptionInContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[entity name]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(thingId like[c] %@)", sessionID];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];  **<-- Pause lands me here**

if (!results || error || 0 == results.count){
    return nil;
}

return [results objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Can you at least show us how you set up your fetch request? Also, how large is your datastore?

Comment: Hard to know exactly, but rather than like[c] it looks like you want to use ==. Also, you should set a fetch limit if you are just looking to return one object.

Comment: Is this app threaded at all? I've seen accidental misuse of a managed object context off the queue on which it was created lead to deadlock. Can you show us the fully expanded stack trace, including the internal system call names that it returns?

Comment: What is contextForCurrentThread?

Comment: its Restkit. It gets a managedObjectContext for the current thread so if in an NSManagedObject you use currentThread when searching you won't search on the main thread.

Comment: Tommy how do I get to the full stack trace?

Comment: I don't see that definition.  In which file is it?

Comment: I didn't post it as it isn't my code its Restkits. Its a helper class method like [NSDate date].

Comment: I know it is, but I looked through RestKit's extensions and I didn't find that method. so I asked which RestKit file it was declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer I moved away from using "LIKE [c]" and now using "==" instead. I also moved away from using [AppDelegate managedObjectContext] in my app when fetching anything and instead using contextForCurrentThread.

By doing both of these my app has stopped freezing.

Comment: You may also benefit from making `thingId` an indexed property in your data model. This will speed up fetches at a cost of slightly increasing the time to add an object to your store.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that the query you are performing goes through a lot of records, and it takes a long time to get those records. Try to make that fetch in a background thread, and move the objectIDs of the records to the main thread. The application will not crash because you are running the debugger at that moment. It's very likely that you will get a crash if you run your application directly from the device and not from Xcode.

Comment: What does "move the objectID's of the record to the main thread"? Do you have a specific example?